# Accessing symfony 1.4 URL using CLI Terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron, symfony-1.4, command-line-interface

Can anyone tell me, how to **access an action URL of symfony** using terminal in ubuntu?
For Example:

```
http://mysymfonyproject.com/index.php/users/sendnewsletter
```

Same way, I want to set up an action class URL as **cron job**. Is it possible to set up **cron jobs** in symfony?
For Example:

```
 http://mysymfonyproject.com/index.php/crons/sendnewsletter
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a Symfony Task is what you should look into. There's a lot of built-in tasks, but you probably should write your own task and then call it from cli using a command:

```
php symfony yourTaskNamespace:yourTaskName
```

Then you can add such command as a regular cronjob task.

You can check detailed instruction how to create custom Symfony tasks at [Documentation Page](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/13-Leveraging-the-Power-of-the-Command-Line)

Comment: Yeah, Tomasz Madeyski, I have created a Symfony Task and accessed using CLI.
$ cd your/project/directory
$ php symfony task-namespace:task-name

Also, for accessing config and doctrine, we need to add options using sfCommandOption class. Thanks :)

I have to go for setting it in server crontab. :)

Comment: Partially solved, because I have to know about setting this symfony task in apache cron tabs :) Since I got a situation to create and execute the symfony action script using CLI alone (not through any browser), I was searching for it. Later on, I got symfony task know, so I have done my things partially :)

Answer (score 0):

Using tasks is the best solution (as Tomasz Madeyski suggested). Just be aware that the tasks work a bit differently than the web app (e.g. read about using `sfContext` in tasks)

You can also use `curl` to access your sf pages directly from CLI:

```
curl -sS  http://mysymfonyproject.com/index.php/crons/sendnewsletter >> mylog.log
```

The `-sS` option will make `curl` silent unless there's an error. You can skip that if you don't need it.

The last part (`>> mylog.log`) will append the result of the request to the log file (it's best if you specify whole path to the log file)

As for setting the cron job it's fairly easy no matter if you use `curl` or sf tasks. Have a look around the web for a tutorial on setting the crontab, there's plenty of them out there.